# Issue for and lists and separate characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am doing a script where I want to change the order of some sentences

```
n = 4
l=[]
t = []
for i in range(n):
    line = input()
    if i%2 == 0:
        t += line
    else:
        l+=line
for i in range(len(l)):
     print(l[i])
for i in range(len(t)):
     print(t[i])
```

I input, in order, the following lines:

```
I like Trains
I like apples
I like pears
I like bananas
```

I want it to print:

```
I like apples,
I like bananas,
I like Trains,
I like pears,
```

but it doesn't prints it, it prints separate letters.

Answer (score 2):

You are *extending* the lists, rather than appending. Extending adds the separate elements from your strings to the lists.

Instead of `+=`, use `list.append()`:

```
t.append(line)
```

and

```
l.append(line)
```

Aside from that, you can drastically simplify your printing loops; you can loop *directly* over a list and get the values, there is no need to generate indices with `range()`:

```
for line in l:
    print(line)
for line in t:
    print(line)
```

You can pass the *whole list* to `print()` and tell it to print each value with a newline in between:

```
print(*l, sep='\n')
print(*t, sep='\n')
```

Comment: How does exactly print(*l, sep="/n") works? What is /n? Sorry, I have never used print() with 2 arguments...

Comment: @NoCUBes: `\n` is the escape sequence for a newline, the character that tells your terminal or console or text editor that the line has ended and to start a new line for the text that follows. `function(*<expression>)` tells Python to take all values from a sequence (produced by the expression) and apply the values as separate arguments. If `l = ['foo', 'bar']`, then `print(*l)` would be the same thing as `print('foo', 'bar')`. So `print(*l, sep='\n')` prints all values in `l` separately, writing a newline between each.

Comment: print(*l) means: print all the items in the list l. If you use sep="\n" each item will start in a new line. If you use sep=";" after each item a ";" will be printed and so on. It's the pythonic way to make things easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 4
l = []
t = []
for i in range(n):
    line = input(">")
    if i % 2 == 0:
        t.append(line)
    else:
        l.append(line)
for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i])
for i in range(len(t)):
    print(t[i])
```

Output

```
>I like apple
>I like train
>I like beer
>I like bear
I like train
I like bear
I like apple
I like beer
>>>
```

## Or... like Martijn said

```
n = 4
l = []
t = []
for i in range(n):
    line = input(">")
    if i % 2 == 0:
        t.append(line)
    else:
        l.append(line)

print(*l, sep="\n")
print(*t, sep="\n")
```

output

```
>1 line
>2 line
>3 line
>4 line
2 line
4 line
1 line
3 line
>>>
```